# How can I ignore / skip 'n' elements while sorting string in a lexicographical order

Tags: c#, linq, algorithm, sorting

I have the following c# code that sorts a string in a lexicographical (alphabetical) order.

```
string str = "ACGGACGAACT";
```

`IEnumerable<string> sortedSubstrings =
                    Enumerable.Range(0, str.Length)
                    .Select(i => str.Substring(i))
                    .OrderBy(s => s);`

Result:
0  AACT 
1  ACGAACT 
2  ACGGACGAACT 
3  ACT 
4  CGAACT 
5  CGGACGAACT 
6  CT 
7  GAACT 
8  GACGAACT 
9  GACGAACT 
10 T

However I want to enhance this sort by skipping the 3rd and the 4th character during the lexicographical sort process

In this case the lexicographical sort will be different to the one above.

result:
0  AA[CT 
1  AC[T 
2  AC[GG]ACGAACT 
3  AC[GA]ACT 
4  CG[GA]CGAACT 
5  CG[AA]CT 
6  CT 
7  GA[CG]AACT 
8  GA[AC]T 
9  GG[AC]GAACT 
10 T

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by tweaking the lambda passed to `OrderBy`. Something like this should do it:

```
var sortedSubstrings = 
    Enumerable.Range(0, str.Length)
    .Select(i => str.Substring(i))
    .OrderBy(s => s.Length < 3 ? s : s.Remove(2, Math.Min(s.Length - 2, 2)));
```

**Edit:** Corrected off-by-one error.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the lambda passed to `OrderBy` to one which will remove the 3rd and 4th symbols from the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sorted = source.OrderBy(s => new string(s.Where((ch, n) => n != 2 && n != 3).ToArray()));
```